# Binding to 2 Datasources

Tags: wpf, listbox, datatemplate, itemtemplate, itemssource

I want to bind my Datatemplate to 2 Datasources, one datasource that will actually define what is in the ListBox and other that will determine how many ListBoxes are there and what Items in the Listbox are selected\checked.

I have following XAML

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="TokenListTemplate">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <CheckBox x:Name="chkToken" IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Text}" />
            </CheckBox>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="ItemTemplate">
        <Border BorderThickness="1">
            <StackPanel Margin="3">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Header}"/>
                <ListBox ItemTemplate="{StaticResource TokenListTemplate}" 
                         ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Tokens}" >
                </ListBox>
            </StackPanel>
        </Border>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid>
    <ListBox ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ItemTemplate}" 
             ItemsSource="{Binding}">
        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WrapPanel/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

And this is the codebehind

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        ObservableCollection<DataEntity> _actualObjects;

        List<Token> tokens1 = new List<Token>() 
                                            { 
                                                new Token("1"),                                                     
                                                new Token("2"), 
                                                new Token("3"), 
                                                new Token("4") 
                                            };

        List<Token> tokens2 = new List<Token>() 
                                            { 
                                                new Token("11"),                                                     
                                                new Token("21"), 
                                                new Token("31")
                                            };

        _actualObjects = new ObservableCollection<DataEntity>()
            {
                new DataEntity(tokens1, "A", "1,2,3", 1),  
                new DataEntity(tokens1, "B", "2,3", 1),
                new DataEntity(tokens2, "C", "21,31", 2)
            };


        DataContext = _actualObjects;
    }

    class DataEntity
    {
        public DataEntity(List<Token> tokens, string header, string tokenString, int entityTypeId)
        {
            Tokens = tokens;
            Header = header;
            TokenString = tokenString;
            EntityTypeId = entityTypeId;
        }
        public List<Token> Tokens { get; set; }
        public String Header { get; set; }
        public String TokenString { get; set; }
        public int EntityTypeId { get; set; }

    }

    public class Token
    {
        public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
        public string Text { get; set; }
        public Token(string text)
        {
            this.IsSelected = false;
            this.Text = text;
        }
    }
}
```

It produces this 
[image]

I don't want to inject token1 or token2 List into DataEntity object so in other words I want DataEntity constructor to be

```
public DataEntity(string header, string tokenString, int entityTypeId)
```

Listbox DataTemplate should select

- tokens1 List as datasource for its LisBoxItems if
  Dataentity.EntityTypeId = 1
- tokens2 List as datasource for its LisBoxItemsif
  DataEntity.EntityTypeId = 2

Also TokenString in DataEntity should be bound to items in the Listbox i.e. if Listbox shows 1   2   3   4
and DataEntity for this listbox has its TokenString value set to "1,2,3" then 1 2 3 should be checked in the listbox
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend to create a ViewModel as a layer between your model and the view. In the ViewModel you can arrange the data to fit to the used controls without changing your model.

So the ViewModel could for example split the tokenString of the DataEntity into a list of tokens.

Just Google for MVVM (Model-View-ViewModel) for examples and furter explanations or look here on SO (like [MVVM: Tutorial from start to finish?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1405739/mvvm-tutorial-from-start-to-finish)).

Answer (score 0):

You're not thinking about this correctly. You need to create one class (some may call a view model) with the responsibility of providing *all* of the data that the view (or UI) will need. Therefore, you will need to have one property which holds a collection of type `DataEntity` (if I understand you correctly) to 'define what is in the outer `ListBox`' as you say.

Then you need a `DataTemplate` to describe what should be displayed for each item in the `ListBox` - your 'ItemTemplate' template. This `DataTemplate` should have another `ListBox` inside in which to display your `Token` objects. Your `DataEntity` should have something like this property in it:

```
public List<Token> Tokens 
{
    get 
    {
        if (EntityTypeId == 1) return tokens1;
        else if (EntityTypeId == 2) return tokens2;
    }
}
```

You will then need another `DataTemplate` for your `Token` objects - your 'TokenListTemplate' template, but without the `StackPanel`... the inner `ListBox` replaces that, eg. if there are two `Token` objects in one `DataEntity` object, then that object would show two `Checkbox`es... you have correctly bound the `IsChecked` property to the `Token.IsSelected` property.

This may be complicated, but it is entirely possible. Just start with the first layer and get your `DataEntity` objects displayed in the outer `ListBox` using your 'ItemTemplate' template. Once that bit is ok, move on to the inner `ListBox`. Good luck.

Comment: Exposing Tokens from within DataEntity is what I am trying to prevent because Tokens list is only for the UI and it has no meaning in my business entity.

Comment: @user2071531 you can put this logic into the new class proposed by Sheridan (the viewmodel). The idea of a viewmodel is to hold information that is used only for the UI (the view) but has no meaning to the business entities (the model).